# How to run CLI commands in PHP on another server using SSH?

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

I am trying to run CLI commands in PHP but on a different server. In order to run the command on the other server I am using the linux `ssh` command. In order to run the CLI command in PHP I am using `exec()`.

This works...

```
$output = exec('cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd'); //works!
```

This works from the command line of one server to another...

```
ssh my.otherserver.com "date"
```

But, when I try to do this in PHP it does not work...

```
$output = exec('ssh my.otherserver.com "date"'); //does not work!
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add the user name before the remote server , root@my.otherserver.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ssh2_connect or phpseclib**

You can use ssh2_connect or phpseclib. On my EC2 instance I had to install the package for ssh2_connect (e.g. yum install php56-pecl-ssh2-0.12-5.15.amzn1.x86_64) as it wasn't there by default.  Note: this could be done with a bash script as well.

```
<?php

//ssh2_connect:
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls -l > /tmp/worked.txt');

//phpseclib:
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.example.com');
$ssh->login('username', 'password') or die("Login failed");
echo $ssh->exec('command');
```

Further reading:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Answer (score 2):

Require:

```
sudo apt install php-ssh2
```

This example will receive the output of `ls -a` from the remote server.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$com = ssh2_connect('223.245.xx.xx', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($com, 'root', 'password');
$shell = ssh2_shell($com, 'xterm');
$stream = ssh2_exec($com, 'ls -a');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($out);
```

It can be secured
furthermore with [cryptographic keys](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php) and [else](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-shell.php).

Answer (score 1):

to connet to your server with ssh you need to use `ssh2_exec` php function.

I recommed you to use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), it's a wrapper for PHP SSH implementation