# PHP's exec() returns a different result than running the command in the shell

Tags: php

so I've read a lot of similar questions on here, none have answered my question.

The problem is that whenever I run `crontab -l` in PHP using `exec()` or `shell_exec()`, it gives me "no crontab for X" (where X is my username), and if I run the same command in the shell (via SSH), I get the correct result.

N.b. this is on a University system, and PHP runs with each individual user's privileges. So even if I run `whoami` on both PHP and the shell, the output will be my username in both cases.

Comment: You don't need to have sudo powers to manage your own crontab

Comment: I think that the problem is that the HTTP Server use a different php than the one that you use through SSH (that is the system default one). So you can try to execute the command through SSH like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525256/how-to-run-cli-commands-in-php-on-another-server-using-ssh)

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind: Security software (perhaps something like AppArmor) preventing access to the crontab directory by children of web server process, or the server running in a root jail.